# PHP - How to add the letter 'a' after each consonant from a string in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops, foreach

I need to put an `a` after each consonant in an array so that for example:

`hello` result will be : `haelalao`

Comment: First of all - this is a good place to get basic knowledge about PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: The basic idea is to loop your array and then use `str_replace()` about 20 times to replace each consonant with itself and add an `a`

Comment: do your homework by yourself, dont cheat :) HINT: you should create an array with all consonant's as a key ($consonant = array('b'=>1, 'c'=>1...) and check for each letter in your string if isset($consonant[$currentLetter])

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - No need to loop, str_replace accepts arrays as arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the  easiest way to do it:

```
preg_replace('/[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]/i', '${0}a', 'hello'); // => haelalao
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/137012)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$str = "hello";
$vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
$arr1 = str_split($str);//convert your string to array
$arr_new = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    array_push($arr_new, $value);
    if (!in_array($value, $vowel)) {
        array_push($arr_new, 'a');
    }
}

print_r($arr_new);//print your array here
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Without a `foreach` , However, internal loopings apply..

```
$str="hello";
$srch=array_diff(str_split($str),array('a','e','i','o','u'));
echo str_replace('aa','a',str_replace($srch,array_map(function ($v){ return $v.'a';},$srch),$str));
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
haelalao
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/136957)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = 'hello';
$vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
$new = str_split($str);
$converted = '';
foreach ($new as $each) {
  if(in_array($each, $vowels)) {
    $converted .= $each;
  } else {
    $converted .= $each.'a';
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ConvertString($convert) {   
    return preg_replace('/[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]/i', '${0}a', '$convert'); 
}

echo ConvertString("Hello");
```